# Android: Html.fromHtml() method weird issue

Tags: android, textview

I am facing a weird issue:

My source string for Html.fromHtml() is as follows:

```
<strong>Terrible experience with Nikko hotel</strong><br />It was not easy to cancel booking. I called to cancel books, but they still chraged us two full days. A reason was we were late ten minutes in calling to cancel. They explained us very kindly that I can only cancel the first day. But they charged after then.\nSick."
```

which is retrieved from a json response

Now, when I display it using setText as follows:

```
commentbox.setText(Html.fromHtml(cmnt.getString("cmnt")));
```

but the output which i see is as follows:

[image]

Why is it giving me italic text instead of bold?

Comment: Try to increase the width of the textview so your strong text to fit in 1 line and see what's happening :)

Comment: width is wrapcontent, that shouldnt be an issue , its happening at other places too :(

Comment: hm... remove the strong and replace it with <b> tags and see what's happening :)

Comment: sadly , its a json response from a server, can try replacing <strong> with <b> or <em>..thanks

Comment: Check for the supported tags list
http://javatechig.com/2013/04/07/how-to-display-html-in-android-view/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be a **LIMITATION** as described [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-anddown):

the Html.fromHtml() method in Android that creates a SpannedString from HTML source **flips `<em>` `and <strong>` tags,** so what you might be used to seeing in boldface turns into italics and vice-versa. This should only be an issue if you are displayng the generated HTML in a TextView — WebView in particular should behave more normally.

Comment: i hv found an issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3473)

also you can use <b> instead

Comment: thanks, wil hav to check for tags and then reverse it before using fromHtml()